# Что делать если экрана не хватает?

Tags: java, android

Во общем некоторых кнопок нету тк маленький экран, как добавить скролл? (если экрана не хватает - прокрутить вниз)

Comment: оберните элементы в `scrollview`

Comment: Пытался, `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child`

Comment: данный контейнер может иметь только одного прямого потомка, как вариант использовать `linearlayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        //тулбар
       <ScrollView 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
             //Ваши кнопки
       </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Все, понял. Надо было все в LinerLayout, а его обернусь в ScrollView

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев Рад был помочь, если мой ответ является правильным, то отметьте галочкой с боку от ответа:)